# Decipher a long sequence of numbers

Tags: mathematics, cipher, pattern, calculation-puzzle, computer-puzzle

> 15268730396752983028873037877312952898251630399865298251987245993029873127730076924579528253883028312898303995273127825262417312965272516303830372449752686302992536776251872526931279711489665267821478724177251699624576811268526783109824167925197245652924177251787241782538786302873119768312852668312686625268245686752824473216878253830287925175273039778250852831287672527245665263006725397251762529312811498

This is a simpler version of [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121599/decrypt-the-message-from-the-qr-code).

Look for patterns.

Comment: On Meta: [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Plaintext

> Do not go gentle into that good night. Rage, rage against the dying of the light.

## Solve Path

Your previous puzzle was deleted. Because I kept notes on my attempts at solving it, I have solved them both by comparing the two texts. This is hardly the intended solution, but a solve is a solve.

> By writing the two texts one above the other I could see several common sequences which suggested they had the same plaintext:
>
> ```
> 15268730396752983028873037877312952898251630399865298251987245993029873127730076 ...
> 15276883039877526302763039878312652892518993039675262517245878302931278300788724 ...
> ```

> I added spaces to both texts to line up the common sequences...
>
> ```
> 152 687303967 529830288730378773129528982516  3039986529825198724599 3029873127730076 ...
> 15276883039877526 30276 303987831265289 251899303967 526 25172  458783029  3127830078 ...
> ```

> And inferred that the digits `6789` were meaningless "null" characters. Replacing them with spaces showed that the remaining digits were in small groups.
>
> ```
> 152   303   52  302   303    312 52   251 303    52  251   245  302   312 ...
> ```

> I replaced each unique group with a letter...
>
> ```
> ABCDBECFBCFGDEHGCIDEBCEJKECFBBLCDIFJEMCNKFGOCPKFGCKFKIDQECEJGCLRIDFCBSCEJGCHIFJEM
> ```

> Replaced the letter C, which accounted for more than 15% of the text, with a space...
>
> ```
> AB DBE FB FGDEHG IDEB EJKE FBBL DIFJEM NKFGO PKFG KFKIDQE EJG LRIDF BS EJG HIFJEM
> ```

> ... [and solved it as a simple substitution](https://quipqiup.com/).
>
> ```
> MO NOT GO GENTLE INTO THAT GOOD NIGHTZ WAGER PAGE AGAINST THE DYING OF THE LIGHTZ
> ```

> Eh, close enough. I corrected the plaintext and recovered the substitution key:
>
> ```
> DO NOT GO GENTLE INTO THAT GOOD NIGHT. RAGE, RAGE AGAINST THE DYING OF THE LIGHT.
>
>    52
> , 112
> . 114
> D 152
> R 214
> A 241
> D 244
> E 245
> F 250
> G 251
> H 252
> I 253
> L 300
> N 302
> O 303
> R 310
> S 311
> T 312
> Y 321
>   52
> ```

> I quickly spotted that an ASCII space with value `32` in decimal was represented as `52`, which is the same value written in Base 6. With the system known, I recovered the original plaintext:
>
> ```
> Do not go gentle into that good night. Rage, rage against the dying of the light.
> ```

Comment: This is a clever (and sneaky!) way to crack this cipher puzzle. Definitely valid, albeit not intended - then again, when presented with a string of numbers: whatcha gonna do??

Comment: rot13(Zl bevtvany qvntabfvf jnf "Inevnoyr-fvmr fhofgvghgvba jvgu tebhcf bs sbhe be svir qvtvgf, serryl erbeqrerq" juvpu jnf bayl unys jebat. Vg jnf inevnoyr-fvmrq, ohg V qvqa'g rkcrpg vg gb or svsgl creprag ahyyf ol yratgu!)

Comment: @codewarrior0 Thank you for the solution! The message is correct, although ciphering process is totally different xD If anyone is curious - I took unicode character position, converted it into base 6 and put groups of digits from 6 to 9 between them to differentiate between characters. I overdid it with QR codes and reversing, yes... Having more than one string of numbers certainly helped.

Comment: Also, randomness of filling groups allowed to make different strings of characters when a string of numbers is split into groups of 3 and then every group is converted into a unicode character. This was a part of the deleted puzzle with QR codes.